# C++ Difference Between const char* and const char[]

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, char, google-nativeclient

I read a question on the difference between:

```
const char*
```

and

```
const char[]
```

where as for a while, I though arrays were just syntactic sugar for pointers.
But something is bugging me, I have a pice of code similar to the following:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    const char* str = { 'b', 'l', 'a', 'h' };
}
```

I get, error: scaler object 'str' requires one element in initializer.
So, I tried this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    const char str[] = { 'b', 'l', 'a', 'h' };
}
```

It worked, at first I thought this may have to do with the fact that an extra operation is applied
when it is a const char*, and GCC is never a fan of operations being performed outside a function (which is bad practice anyway), but the error does not seem to suggest so.
However in:

```
void Func() {
    const char* str = { 'b', 'l', 'a', 'h' };
}
```

It compiles just fine as expected. Does anyone have any idea why this is so?

x86_64/i686-nacl-gcc 4(.1.4?) pepper 19 tool - chain (basically GCC).

Comment: One's an array and one's a pointer.

Comment: ...and if you think they're the same, think again.

Comment: @WhozCraig Like I said, I read a question explaining that they are different (where as before I thought arrays were syntactic sugar for pointers and basically a collection of overloaded operators).

Comment: @chris It seems strange thought that the compiler could not resolve that as a constant.

Comment: The last snippet also does *not* compile on my clang (Apple LLVM 4.2, clang-425.0.28) so I dunno what is up with yours. (error: "Excess elements in scaler initializer"), but I didn't expect it to.

Comment: @WhozCraig Strange... I always thought declaring a pointer to an array and an array like that was in the standard. 0.0

Comment: I refer you to the *C* FAQ on this: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, it doesn't make a difference if you try to use compound initialization at namespace scope or in a function: neither should work! When you write

```
char const* str = ...;
```

you got a pointer to a sequence of `char`s which can, e.g., be initialized with a string literal. In any case, the `char`s are located somewhere else than the pointer. On the other hand, when you write

```
char const str[] = ...;
```

You define an array of `char`s. The size of the array is determined by the number of elements on the right side and, e.g., becomes 4 your example `{ 'b', 'l', 'a', 'h' }`. If you used, e.g., `"blah"` instead the size would, of course, be 5. The elements of the array are copied into the location where `str` is defined in this case.

Note that `char const x[]` *can* be equivalent to writing `char const* x` in some contexts: when you declare a function argument, `char const x[]` actually is the same as `char const*`.

Comment: When you write *"is the same"* should you not rather say *"can be implicitly converted"*?

Comment: I did not know this had different behavior in different contexts, thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @IInspectable In reference to typedefs, would that be on an instance by instance basis or upon declaration of the type?

Comment: @IInspectable: No. Function arguments declared as `char const x[]` and `char const* x` are identical. However, they actually _are_ different when used as `typdef`s but I haven't quite figured out how. Here is a test: `void f(char const x[], char const* y) { std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value << '\n'; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I misinterpreted `char const x[]` to mean *any explicitly sized array*. Without a size argument they are indeed identical when used as types in a function signature.

Comment: @IInspectable: Even if you mentioned a size in the brackets, the type would still be a `char const*`: that is, `void f(char const x[10])` is equivalent to `void f(char const* x)`! Instead of `10` you can use any other positive value!

Comment: @DietmarKühl [Modified example](http://ideone.com/iZ318W) to demonstrate what I *think* you were referring to concerning differences as typedefs (and strangely, the same). That's a real noodle-baker. I think I may have finally found my first SO question. Thank you.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That is, indeed, an interesting example! I haven't got to the bottom of that one, yet.

Comment: @DietmarKühl [Posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626126/why-are-char-and-char-as-typedefs-different-but-sometimes-not). I have a long drive, but will check in when I get home. Thanks for the brain food.