# Why are char[] and char* as typedefs different, but sometimes... not?

Tags: c++, decltype

The following observation arose as I was following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625674/c-difference-between-const-char-and-const-char) about `char[]` and `char*` differences.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char ar[];
typedef char* pr;
void f2(ar x, pr y)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<ar, pr>::value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    char data[] = "data";
    char *ptr = data;
    f2(data,ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** ( on Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) )

```
1
0
```

Why do these report as different types, but not different `decltype()`s ? My suspicion is they are in fact different *types* due to their `typedef` declarations, but then why are variables reported as the *same* type?

Comment: Decaying? (as function parameters)

Comment: (Elaborating on my comment:) The parameter types of the function are "decayed" as per [dcl.fct]/5: "After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`”, respectively". Therefore `decltype(x)` is *pointer to `char`*, not *array of unknown bound of `char`* (unlike `ar`).

Comment: @DyP Thank you for the standard reference, sir.

Comment: @WhozCraig You may want to check the std::decay (at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay).

Comment: May the only question you ever asked get you to the magical 20k!!! And may I be the first to congratulate you...

Comment: @Floris heh. thank you! very kind of you. I look back on this question now and wonder why I never saw the answer myself =)

Comment: Wow. I guess I irked someone out there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C++, as in C, a parameter that's declared to be of array type is *adjusted* (at compile time) to be of pointer type, specifically a pointer to the array's element type.

This happens whether the array type is specified directly or via a typedef (remember that a typedef doesn't create a new type, just an alias for an existing type).

So this:

```
typedef char ar[];
typedef char* pr;
void f2(ar x, pr y)
{
    // ...
}
```

really means:

```
void f2(char* x, char* y)
{
    // ...
}
```

Another rule, also shared by C and C++, is that an *expression* of array type is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly *converted* to a pointer to the first element of the array object.  Which means that if you define an array object:

```
char arr[10];
```

you can use the name of that object as an argument to a function that takes a `char*` parameter (which loses the bounds information).

In C, the cases where this implicit conversion *doesn't* happen are:

1. When the array expression is the operand of `sizeof` (`sizeof arr` yields the size of the array, not the size of a pointer);
2. When the array expression is the operand of unary `&` (`&arr` is a pointer-to-array, not a pointer-to-pointer); and
3. When the array expression is a string literal used to initialize an object of array type (`char s[] = "hello";` initializes `s` as an array, not as a pointer).

None of these cases (or the other cases that occur in C++) appear in your program, so your call:

```
f2(data,ptr);
```

passes two pointer values of type `char*` to `f2`.

Inside `f2`, the parameter objects `x` and `y` are both of type `char*`, so `std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value` is true.

But the types `ar` and `pr` are distinct. `ar` is an incomplete array type `char[]`, and `pr` is the pointer type `char*`.

Which explains your program's output. The weirdness happens because the parameter `x`, which you defined with the array type `ar`, is really of type `char*`, which is the same type as `pr`.

Comment: Thank you, Keith. This was very well presented, and in-concert with Dyp's standard reference from general comment, explains precisely what is being seen. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The C family is pass-by-value, and the C value of an array is a pointer to its first element.  When you pass an item declared to be an array to a function, what's really getting passed is that pointer, and C treats the prototype as if you declared it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code so that we could see how calling a f2 changes the type. Before the call the variables are of different type. After the call they have become same

```
    typedef char ar[];
typedef char* pr;
void f2(ar x, pr y)
{
    cout << is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value << '\n'; //same type
}

int main()
{
    ar data = "data";
    pr ptr = data;
    cout << is_same<decltype(data), decltype(ptr)>::value << '\n'; // different
    f2(data,ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is
0
0
.As @jthill, @Dyp and @keith Thompson says this is because of decaying of the array to pointer.

Comment: Another "visualization" of the issue: `is_same<decltype(x), char[]>` and `is_same<ar, char[]>` inside `f2` (and of course `is_same<decltype(x), char*>`).

Comment: Oh, and something interesting: `is_same<decltype(data), ar>` is also `false` (because `ar` is incomplete and [basic.types]/6 says they're different).